# ¿Porqué no funciona esta Base de Datos?

Tags: php, html5, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Me gustaría saber porqué cuando ejecuto el `index.html` y aprieto el botón no me funciona me da el siguiente error:

> Esta página no funciona
>
> La página localhost no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora. HTTP ERROR
>   500

Sería de gran ayuda que resolvieseis mi duda ya que soy novato en php y mysql. Os dejo el código. Ah, uso Phpmyadmin.

validar.php

```
<pre>
<?php  

$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","Ciemrcraol") or die ("<h2>No se encuentra el servidor</h2>");
$db=mysql_select_db("datos",$link) or die ("<h2>Error de conexión</h2>");

//Valores del formulario
$nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
$nick=$_POST['nick'];
$email=$_POST['correo'];
$passwd=$_POST['contraseña'];

//Obtener longitud de string
$req=(strlen($nombre)*strlen($nick)*strlen($email)*strlen($passwd)) or die ("No se han llenado todos los campos");

$contraseñaUsuario=md5($passwd);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO  datos VALUES ('', $nombre, '$nick', '$email', '$contraseñaUsuario')",$link) or die ("<h2>Error de envio de datos</h2>");

echo "Guardado correctamente";

?>
</pre>
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="margin-left: 35%;">Registro de usuarios</h1>
<form action="validar.php" method="POST">
<table style="margin-left: 40%">
 <tr>
  <td><p>Nombre Completo</p><input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><p>Nickname</p><input type="text" name="nick" placeholder="nombre01"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><p>Correo</p><input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="algo@algo.com"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td><p>Contraseña</p><input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="secreto"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button style="margin-left: 40%;" type="submit">Registrar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola prueba colocando esta función de php print_r(error_get_last()); exit(); para determinar cuál es el último error.

Comment: No imprime nada, no sale el error pero la pantalla se queda en blanco.

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo que uses var_dump(); por cada línea de tu aplicación, con esto te darás cuenta en que línea se cae y donde es el problema ya que el error 500 no nos dice nada.  echo "<pre>"; var_dump("debug"); exit();

Comment: El resultado es: string(5) "debug"

Comment: ¿Qué significa?

Comment: Hola disculpa la demora en responder, como te indicaba el var_dump solamente es para que identifiques en que línea esta el error y poder enfocarte ahí donde viene el problema si colocas el var_dump en la linea 1 y te muestra debug, entonces todo va bien ponlo en otra línea y así hasta que se caiga la aplicación y puedas hallar en que línea de código esta el problema, nos cuentas

Comment: El programa se cae cuándo pone string(5) "debug", ¿será la línea 5 o un string?

Comment: mmm no entiendo que indicas string(5) "debug" no es cuando se cae es solo el contenido de tu vardump si sale eso es porque todo va bien debes seguir los pasos que te indique anteriormente.

Comment: Ok, gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en la versión de tu PHP, puedes probar con esto:

```
<?php  

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "datos");

    //Valores del formulario
    $nombre =$_POST['nombre'];
    $nick       =$_POST['nick'];
    $correo =$_POST['correo'];
    $passwd =$_POST['contrasena'];

    //Obtener longitud de string
    $req=(strlen($nombre)*strlen($nick)*strlen($correo)*strlen($passwd)) or die ("No se han llenado todos los campos");

    $contrasena=md5($passwd);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO registro (nombre, nick, correo, contrasena) VALUES ('$nombre', '$nick', '$correo', '$contrasena')";

    if ($db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Guardado correctamente";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql;
    }

?>
```

Verifica los campos y la tabla de tu base de datos.